# before method jquery

Tags: jquery, methods

I have a HTML section like this:

```
<li data-file="file.mp3">
    <div class="pink-light playing">
```

Now, I want to get the "data-file" attribute of `<li>`.
But I have several `<li>` tags, and I want to get **only** the
attribute that has a div with "playing" class inside.

My script:

```
$(".playing").before($("li"),function(){

    alert($(this).attr("data-file"));

});
```

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I also made alert($(".playing").before($("li").attr("data-file"))); but it won't work (I get an error inside jquery.js).

Comment: `before` doesn't do anything remotely like what you've tried to use it for above. Spend an hour reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It literally takes only that long, and will save you a *lot* of time.

Comment: .before is used to insert data. You need to look for $("li > div.playing") and within that you need to do a $(this).parent().attr("data-file") to get the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing it. If the `.playing` element will be unique, then:

```
var file = $(".playing").closest("li").attr("data-file");
```

[`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) finds the closest ancestor that matches a given selector. Since your `.playing` element is a child (descendant) of the `li`, that's how you can find it.

Alternately, you could use the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-class:

```
var file = $("li:has(.playing)").attr('data-file');
```

...but be aware that `:has` is a jQuery thing, so it can't delegate to the selector engine.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use .before like it was .closest

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 $(".playing").each(function(){
  alert($(this).parent().attr("data-file"));
 });
```

Note : use prop instead of attr

Comment: *"Note : use prop instead of attr"* Why? As the OP is reading the value of an attribute, not of a property, `attr` is **exactly** the right tool. Second choice would be `data`, but `prop` just isn't on the list.

Answer (score 1):

[`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) is only used to **insert** new elements. If you want to retrieve, use [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) instead. Though, in your case, you're not really interested in the previous sibling, but in the [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) node, since the `div` is inside the `li`:

```
$(".playing").parent().each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("data-file"));
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder just noticed that, I was under impression that the `li` and `div` were siblings (silly, I know, but that's what I get for skimming the question too fast...). Answer updated.